# Minecraft Spigot plugin not running

Tags: java, intellij-idea, minecraft, spigot

I have started java a week ago and I am trying to make a Minecraft plugin but it is not working. In the tutorial I'm watching the guy says to run the script to get a .jar file for it, the problem is that I can't press the run button (on IntelliJ) because it says "The file in the editor is not runnable". I think I know the reason but I still can't fix it. I think the problem is that I need a file for it to run off but nothing showing up (blue circle). Can anyone help?

[image]

I couldn't find anything similar and even asked some friends I know that are a bit more experienced but we couldn't anything that helped.

Comment: Welcome to SO! If you follow a tutorial it would be useful to *include a link to the tutorial you follow*! I see a `pom.xml` in there, which suggests this project is set up to use Maven. You probably need to execute some Maven goal to build your jar file (which was *probably* set up in the run configuration earlier in the tutorial).

Answer (score 1):

If you have not done so yet, install the plugin "Minecraft Development" it helps you set up dependencies and all the other things you need for minecraft plugins. After that, just create a new project with the plugin.

Comment: As indicated by the Spigot icon on their project, it is highly likely that they have already installed it.  Great recommendation on using it, however, but maybe include how to install and use it?  (File > New Project > Minecraft)

Answer (score 0):

Do you see "Maven" on the right side of your screen? Click and choose on your plugin Name, then "Lifecycle" and after this click "Package". Grab your compiled plugin in Project "target" folder.